# How to parse string to list in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to parse string to list in Python ?

```
myStringValue = "[['5', 1], ['1', 5], ['3', 3], ['3', 6], ['4', 5], ['4', 3], ['4', 5], ['6', 6], ['4', 1], ['3', 4]]"
```

How to convert `myStringValue` to list ?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(..)`

Answer (score 2):

Be careful when using it as it's open to exploitation, but `eval()` is one way forward:

```
>>> myStringValue = "[['5', 1], ['1', 5], ['3', 3], ['3', 6], ['4', 5], ['4', 3], ['4', 5], ['6', 6], ['4', 1], ['3', 4]]"
>>> eval(myStringValue)
[['5', 1], ['1', 5], ['3', 3], ['3', 6], ['4', 5], ['4', 3], ['4', 5], ['6', 6], ['4', 1], ['3', 4]]
>>> type(eval(myStringValue))
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: `json` or `ast` modules would be better here